# Open Office Calc formating table

Tags: openoffice, format, spreadsheet

Instead of data, I would like the first row to be the names of the columns. How can I do this? One of the reasons I want this is so that if the rows are rearranged the names wont be jumbled up. I think this may be called **headings** but am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly in LibreOffice, this is very easy. Make sure your columns have names (meaningful or even just A, B, C ...), select the applicable range (including headers - you are right about the terminology) then Format > Autoformat, OK. Thereafter the headers should stay put even if the rest of the table (data) is sorted.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had a humerus experience, when I was trying things out the date got converted into the format 1999-12-31 then when I auto-formatted it must've thought it was an equation and subtracted the numbers...such a silly program.